# React js convert object to arrays for useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Good Day!
I am coding a webshop demo for my portfolio. I am using commerce.js for backend. Problem comes when I try to fetch the data from commerce. It is in the form of objects which are not valid for mapping. I have tried many methods for converting it into array but no use.

Here's my App.js

```
const App = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  const fetchProducts = async () => {
    const { data } = await commerce.products.list();

    //setProducts(data);

    console.log(Object.entries(data));

    //Tried Using Object.values and Object.entries but no use.
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchProducts();
  }, []);
```

When `setProducts` is uncommented, Reactjs throws an error that object is invalid as react child.

This is what my console looks like:

[image]

Here's the Product component in which this data is being used

```
const Product = ({ product }) => {
  //console.log(product);
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Card className={classes.root}>
      <CardMedia
        className={classes.media}
        image={product.media}
        title={product.name}
      />
      <CardContent>
        <div className={classes.cardContent}>
          <Typography variant="h5" gutterBottom>
            {product.name}
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="h5">{product.price}</Typography>
        </div>
        <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary">
          {product.description}
        </Typography>
      </CardContent>
      <CardActions disableSpacing className={classes.cardActions}>
        <IconButton aria-label="Add to Cart">
          <AddShoppingCart />
        </IconButton>
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
  );
};
```

Comment: setProducts(products.map(arr=>{ const [id, value]= arr; return {id, ...value}})) - you can replace     console.log(Object.entries(data));
 and see if this format would suit your needs.

Comment: Given what the console shows (tupels of `[number, object]`) and how [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) works, I'm pretty sure you already get a plain old array of products from the backend. If so, and if an array of products is what you expect, then simply `setProducts(data);` should be enough.

Comment: Can you add info about what is the raw data format and why won't `Object.values` works?

Answer (score 1):

`product.price` is an Object, so you can't just use it as a react child :)

I am referring to this line:

```
<Typography variant="h5">{product.price}</Typography>
```

If you just changed it to

```
<Typography variant="h5">{product.price.formatted}</Typography>
```

It should be fine

Comment: Error is produced when I use setProducts function an set it to data variable.

Comment: @MuhammadAbbas That's how you perceive the origin of the error. Though the error message you posted clearly indicates a problem while react is trying to **render** your component. As such this answer is probably very close or even on the spot, regarding the problem. Provided you pass a valid list of products to `setProducts`, see my comment under your question regarding that.